# python requests. Как правильно подсунуть сертификат КриптоПро?

Tags: python, ssl, requests, openssl

Есть специальный урл у крипто про, для авторизаций, там получают сертификаты. Так вот, я на этот урл могу попасть, только если захожу через IE. Хром и ФФ ни в какую не показывают. Говорят, проблемы с сертификатом.

Сертификат я получил, пытаюсь подсунуть питону, но получаю:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cpca20.cryptopro.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ui/1/Login.aspx (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(0, u'unknown error (_ssl.c:3027)'),))
```

Погуглил, нашел что нужно преобразовать сертификат в pem (у меня он в формате cer).
Преобразовал, получаю ошибку

```
Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: xxxxx
```

Как я понял нужна цепочка сертификатов? А в файлике что получился я четко вижу 1 сертификат. Где брать эту цепочку? Или как то можно ее создать?

код простой, делаю так

```
r = requests.get('https://cpca20.cryptopro.ru/ui/1/Login.aspx', verify='файл.pem')
```

Comment: КритпоПро требует поддержки российских алгоритмов шифрования, которые ни хром, ни фф, ни requests не поддерживают и скорее всего никогда не будут поддерживать.

Answer (score 6):

Это какие-нибудь госконтрактники, которых по закону заставляют использовать российские алгоритмы шифрования? Вы в принципе не можете с ними работать без пересборки OpenSSL с поддержкой гостовых алгоритмов шифрования.

В openssl-1.1.0 поддержку ГОСТ выпилили за устарелость кода и отсутствие мейнтейнера. Есть реализация ГОСТ для 1.0.х: https://github.com/gost-engine/engine/wiki/Building

Вам нужно пересобрать openssl с поддержкой ГОСТ, только тогда вы сможете достучаться до этого сайта.

UPD. Криптопро поддерживает [свой форк openssl](https://github.com/deemru/openssl) (sic!), в котором работают гостовские шифры.
У них есть сборка для Windows, для остальных платформ, я подозреваю, нужно собирать самостоятельно.